# Initialize a dataframe without a header

Tags: python, pandas

To create a pandas dataframe with a header I can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

How would I create one without a header, something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
# seems to create three headers, '0', '1', and '2' for the index of the array.
```

Comment: Mmm, how do you propose to make use of this dataframe with no column names? Why not just have a 2D numpy array, which will be much faster?

Comment: I was thinking I could use the index, perhaps it's already doing that above just explicitly?

Comment: You just get an autoincrementing column name. Use an array and array indexing. Unless there's a specific function in pandas that you need, I think this will be both inefficient and confusing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `zip` to interpret the lists as columns instead of lines (if that is your question):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([*zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])])
df
>>    0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: yes, sorry my question wasn't clear, this is the answer that I was looking for -- thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well what you could do, having created the dataframe, is:

```
df.columns = ['' for i in range(df.shape[1])]
```

However, this is not advisable as the columns are necessary if you want to slice the dataframe